# Material TextInputLayout styles are not working when run on real device app crashes

Tags: android, xml, material-components-android

I have the problem with material components style .
When adding below style into TextInputLayout the app crashes but in android studio preview it shows.

```
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox"
```

Activity code---

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="ORDER`enter code here` NO"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox"

        >

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText

            android:id="@+id/orderNo"
            android:layout_width="173dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:padding="10dp"


            />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

dependency-----

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha10'
    implementation 'com.vivekkaushik.datepicker:datePickerTimeline:0.0.3'



}
```

Comment: Post the crash. Also remove the support libraries dependencies since the material components works with [androidx](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#new-namespace-and-androidx).

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this dependency if your app theme is not Theme.MaterialComponents

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha10'
```

with this

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

Comment: but i checked in my project 1.0.0-alpha1 dependency version is working and 1.1.0-alpha10 is not working

Comment: its also working with stable version 1.0.0 so i edited my answer